# Those who listened to more than 10 mins each month in the last 6 months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out the count of users who listened to more than 10 mins each month in the last 6 months

We have this event: `Song_stopped_listen` and one attribute is `session_progress_ms`

Now I'm trying to see the monthly evolution of the count of this cohort over the last 6 months.

I'm using bigquery and this is the query I tried, but I feel that something is off semantically, but I couldn't put my finger on:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE (timestamp)) AS STRING),"-",CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE (timestamp)) AS STRING)) AS date
,SUM(absl.session_progress_ms/(1000*60*10)) as total_10_ms, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) as total_10_listeners
FROM ios.song_stopped_listen as absl
LEFT JOIN ios.users u on absl.user_id = u.id 
WHERE absl.timestamp > '2018-05-01'
Group by 1 
HAVING(total_10_ms > 1)
```

Please help figure out what I'm doing wrong here. 
Thank you.

data Sample:

```
user_id | session_progress_ms | timestamp
1       |         10000       |    2017-10-10 14:34:25.656 UTC
```

What I want to have:

```
||Month-year | Count of users who listened to more than 10 mins
|2018-5     | 500
|2018-6     | 600
|2018-7     | 300
|2018-8     | 5100
|2018-9     | 4500
|2018-10    | 1500
|2018-11    | 1500
|2018-12    | 2500
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Added the details of the data sample and the desired output. But I don't know how to format a table..

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple levels of aggregation:

```
select user_id
from (select ssl.user_id, timestamp_trunc(timestamp, month) as mon,
             sum(ssl.session_progress_ms/(1000*60)) as total_minutes
      from ios.song_stopped_listen as ssl 
      where date(ssl.timetamp) < date_trunc(current_date, month) and
            date(ssl.timestamp) >= date_add(date_trunc(current_date, month) interval 6 month), 
      group by 1, 2 
     ) u
where total_minutes >= 10 
group by user_id
having count(*) = 6;
```

To get the count, just use this as a subquery with `count(*)`.